# How to I fix a Run-Time Error in Nested Loops for VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, nested-loops

I am having an issue getting the following problem done.

I have to read the given First and Middle names and then I have to output all possible combinations in the columns next to it.

Input:

| First | Middle |
| --- | --- |
| Penelope | Jill |
| Gwyneth | Diane |
| ALice | Heidi |
| Anna | Lily |
|  | Victoria |

I feel like my code is right (or at least pretty close), but I keep getting a Run-time error.

This is my code:

```
Sub LoopsHW2()

Dim First As Range
Dim Middle As Range
Dim FirstOut As String
Dim MidOut As String
Dim oRow As Integer

Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("A3").Activate
oRow = 2

For Each First In Range(Range("A3"), Range("A3").End(x1Down))
    FirstOut = First.Value
    For Each Middle In Range(Range("B3"), Range("B3").End(x1Down))
        MidOut = Middle.Value
        Cells(oRow, "C").Value = FirstOut
        Cells(oRow, "D").Value = MidOut
        oRow = oRow + 1
    Next
    DoEvents
Next
Beep

End Sub
```

My error point to this line of code

```
For Each First In Range(Range("A3"), Range("A3").End(x1Down))
```

and says "Run-time error '1004'. Method 'End' of object 'Range' failed"

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the last row, and then use it to build your `Range`, like this:

```
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For Each First In Range("A3:A" & LastRow)
  ' do Something

Next
```